# Trap will not always remove my tempfile despite being sent the appropriate exit status

Tags: bash

This is my first question on this site so I apologize if it is poor and I will take your advice to improve my future questions.

Background: 
My script is suppose to take an incoming parameter such as -rows || -r || -columns || -c but it should not accept capital leading letter variations of any of those 4.  If a capital variation is found it should exit.  It should also exit if it finds anything but -r or -c (I suppose the first statement is redundant because -r and -R are separated by 32 on the ascii table).  Not only should the script exit, but it should delete the temp file that was previously created.  I am leaving a lot out right now as I am trying to be very to the point.

I have a trap that is set to delete the temp file forcibly, exit with a status of 1 and it is triggered with states 1 2 and 15.

Here is the trap:

```
trap "rm -f $tempFile; exit 1" 1 2 15
```

Here is the conditional statement that should be catching -a, -anyLettersBut-r&&-c

```
if [ "${1:0:2}" != '-r' ] && [ "${1:0:2}" != '-c' ]
then
    echo "Usage: stats {-rows|-cols} [file]" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If I enter my command to invoke the script from the command prompt as a -r, the script runs as it should and the trap works when needed throughout the script.  It removes the tempfile and everything.

But if I invoke the script with a -R or -C, it exits with the Usage error, but the trap does not remove the tempfile.  Why?  What do I not understand that I need to?  What does the computer see?

Please let me know what else you want to see.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Bash has a special signal you can trap: `trap handler EXIT` -- handler fires when the shell is about to exit, no matter what the cause.

Comment: Have you considered using `getopts` by the way? And maybe creating your files after you have checked the parameters? Just a thought ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is actually how I ended up solving it before I posted on here.  It is probably better form to check first then create as you wouldn't want to create, find out the params are incorrect, and then delete.. Much cleaner just to check params then create!

I do not know about getopts, I will check the man page on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trapping signals 1, 2, and 15. On my machine (x86 Linux) these correspond to SIGHUP, SIGINT, and SIGTERM.

But your `if` statement sends none of these signals; it simply exits. I'm not sure why you expect that to generate a signal.

Comment: Those are the correct signals.  I thought by exiting, it sent a signal of 1 which the trap should grab immediately and do what it was told to do (delete the temp file).  

If this is not the case, how do you send a signal?

Comment: @8this Signals are sent with the curiously named `kill` syscall, which bash exposes as the `kill` builtin, e.g. `kill -1 $$`.

Comment: Is there a way to +1 on you or anything so you get credit?  I GREATLY appreciate your help!  Now that I know how to send signals, I can fix my issues!